# Multiple models in single ModelAdmin

Tags: django

Is there any way to register multiple models to single ModelAdmin. I want django to show multiple models in single page. Like inlines but without any foreign key.

I have one user model and another settings model for a single work. It fetches twitter users and their tweets. I get users and tweets together by using TabularInline. However there is another model called settings where a user can determine number of tweets to show, number of tweets per user etc. I want to show all of them in one ModelAdmin/ one page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit two models in one page if one is not related to the other. It is out of the scope of Django Admin.

Django Admin is only intended for simple admin interface. If you need advanced behaviors you will have to write your own views. You can [add views to Django Admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites).