# Django Wagtail Custom web pages in Admin (Multiple models in single ModelAdmin)

Tags: python, django, django-models, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I'm sure i can create a frontend website to do what I'm trying to achieve on top of wagtail.

However because this is purely a backend system for a client I would prefer if they could have this functionality fit in natively on wagtails CMS.

I have a couple of related snippets. 
Driver,Trip,Stops and items.

```
Driver 1-Many Trips
Trips 1-many Stops
Stops 1-many items
```

Now I can edit these just fine but, I would like to say display all the trips a driver makes.

As well as select a trip and see all the stops they made, etc

The gist is that it is related data that I would like to view in a single page and navigate through various levels of data through links.

As far as I have read wagtail backend was not designed to do this. However I am sure the must be away i can simply create a page that feels like the backend and is only visible from "the backend".

I'm just not sure how to go about it.

I would imagine I would create a custom view and model to populate it just as though it was frontend but have it fitted to be accessed in the backend.

I have found the following resources but they keep failing for various errors

[1. Multiple models in single ModelAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36080773/multiple-models-in-single-modeladmin)

[2. Using fields from multiple models](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/XX0p6tLET1g)

[3. Using Proxy Models to Customize the Django Admin](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/using-proxy-models-customize-django-admin/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the closest thing I can think of to have a page have a 'privacy' visibility.

You can also add Menu that require a user to be logged in to view the pages.  I would add some customization on top of it and create a spacial menuItem type that is only visible if the user is logged in.  It won't really look like the admin interface but it has the required permissioning and such and won't affect the user flow.

---

Side Note:

If you can figure out how to add custom link to the admin interface I'd love to know.  For example, my hierarchy for the 80% use case is to navigate to Site->News->Add Child Page then choose blog post.  It'd be nice to just have an easy button that just lets someone create a new blog post that isn't as involved.

Comment: I know that's on option but i really don't feel like it's the best one. 


To asnwer your question it's pretty straight forward. You would need to import your model into your wagtail_hooks.py then simply register it with "modeladmin_register(yourcreatedAdminVersion)"

check out http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/reference/hooks.html

If you post a question i will answer it for you.